# How to check all individual commits in Travis CI for a Github project

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

We are using Travis CI connected to a Github project and it runs tests for the latest commit of each pushed branch. I would like to also check the previous commits between the tip of *master* and the tip of the checked branch.

Rationale: I only want to merge 100% consistent commits that do not break the tests. I do not want to include any inconsistent commits that modify code without fixing the tests or vice versa.

The way I'm doing it locally:

```
git rebase -i master --exec 'nosetests'
```

The project:

https://github.com/vpsfreecz/brutus

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement. Could you expand on *why*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Edited to make the explanation clearer.

Comment: I suppose I meant more broadly - why does it matter that every commit in the whole history passes the tests? Are you expecting all contributors to either rewrite or squash their history? Do you see no value in being able to see and understanding why a commit didn't pass the tests, or how a feature actually developed rather than it just appearing fully-formed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Of course I expect contributors to fix their patches if they dont meet the criteria of the project some of which are enforced using the test suite. I'm not aware of any reason to allow patches that break tests.